# What's the meaning of "shockwave through time measurable"?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminology

In Terminator Dark Fate (2019) there is this conversation:

> T 800: When my mission was completed, there were no further orders. So
>   for 20 years, I kept learning how to become more human.
>
> Grace: So what about the texts?
>
> T 800: When chronal displacement occurs there's a **shockwave through
>   time measurable** before the event.

Explain me this word. It's sound look like some high tech sci-fi quantum word.

> Sarah: That's how, not why.

Comment: “Explain me this word” — which one? You've highlighted four words.

Comment: I would not characterize any of the boldfaced words as high-tech, sci-fi, or "quantum".

Answer (score 7):

The proper punctuation is:

> When chronal displacement occurs there's a shockwave through time, measurable before the event.

Note the comma.  What it means is that when there is time travel ("chronal displacement"), there are shockwaves—disturbances that propagate through the spacetime continuum.  These shockwaves originate in time at the points where the time travel begins and ends.  However, they propagate away from there through time, including backwards in time.  That means that, by searching for such shocks, it is possible to detect that a time travel event is going to occur in the near future.  The appearance of shockwaves, traveling backwards in time, presages the arrival (or departure) of a time traveler.